# ActionLink failed to work on mvc webapp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have created a mvc 3 web app.

_Layout.cshtml contain following menu

```
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", "Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Enquiry", "Enquiry", "Enquiry")</li>
```

For Enquiry I have created new folder `Enquiry` inside `View` folder and create `Enquiry.cshtml` inside it.

Then also i'm getting error :
`Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.`

please help me if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to your error the error page also shows you something like this for `Contact Us`:

> Requested URL: /Home/ContactUs

Ensure you got an action named ContactUs inside your home controller.

and for `Enquiry`

> Requested URL: /Enquiry/Enquiry

Ensure you got an action named Enquiry inside your Enquiry controller.

The ActionLink method has several overrides, you are using this one:

```
ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName);
```

The parameters are:

- linkText: The inner text of the anchor element
- actionName: The name of the action
- controllerName: the name of the controller

So when you specify the below you are saying, show my link text as `Contact Us` and when clicked go to the `ContactUs` action in my `Home` controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", "Home")
```

Make sure all your actions and controller names you specify exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have a *Controllor* as Enquiry and *Action* as Enquiry to
>   render your view Enquiry in View folder

Comment: yes inside Controller folder i have crated EnquiryController.cs too

Comment: I will ask a  silly question, have you compiled your code after you have created your controller? Also, could you paste the controller class to give more clue?